# "fs.existsSync is not a function" without touching anything related

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm building a small web app with angular2, the only dependency so far being bootstrap for a navigation bar. One day, all works fine (including that I can see my navbar), the other day I'm cloning my repo on another machine, run `npm install` and `ng serve`, add some component/services and suddenly end up with the site not loading and this stack trace in the browser (compiling succeeds without errors though):

```
Uncaught TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function
    at devmode.js:33
    at Object.<anonymous> (devmode.js:34)
    at Object.__webpack_require__.constructor.oneshot.fn (devmode.js:34)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 5d37cea67e603e9113e4:52)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http.js:32)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http.js:567)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 5d37cea67e603e9113e4:52)
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:29)
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:255)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 5d37cea67e603e9113e4:52)
    at Object.171 (quote.service.ts:7)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 5d37cea67e603e9113e4:52)
    at Object.170 (routing.module.ts:37)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 5d37cea67e603e9113e4:52)
    at Object.90 (best.component.ts:8)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 5d37cea67e603e9113e4:52)
    at Object.168 (app.component.ts:8)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 5d37cea67e603e9113e4:52)
    at Object.157 (src async:7)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 5d37cea67e603e9113e4:52)
    at Object.342 (main.bundle.js:549)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 5d37cea67e603e9113e4:52)
    at webpackJsonpCallback (bootstrap 5d37cea67e603e9113e4:23)
    at main.bundle.js:1
(anonymous) @ devmode.js:33
(anonymous) @ devmode.js:34
__webpack_require__.constructor.oneshot.fn @ devmode.js:34
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 5d37cea67e603e9113e4:52
(anonymous) @ http.js:32
(anonymous) @ http.js:567
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 5d37cea67e603e9113e4:52
(anonymous) @ index.js:29
(anonymous) @ index.js:255
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 5d37cea67e603e9113e4:52
171 @ quote.service.ts:7
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 5d37cea67e603e9113e4:52
170 @ routing.module.ts:37
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 5d37cea67e603e9113e4:52
90 @ best.component.ts:8
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 5d37cea67e603e9113e4:52
168 @ app.component.ts:8
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 5d37cea67e603e9113e4:52
157 @ src async:7
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 5d37cea67e603e9113e4:52
342 @ main.bundle.js:549
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 5d37cea67e603e9113e4:52
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap 5d37cea67e603e9113e4:23
(anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:1
```

After seeing the error once, I will see it the other machine too if I push & pull, though apparently nothing changed outside the content related logic that I added.

My research so far shows me mostly questions related to electron, which I don't use, or file system operations that I'm not doing. Am I missing something obvious here?

I already did the usual workarounds like deleting node_modules & rerunning `npm i`, I'm on npm version 5.4.0 and node 8.4.0 and I use the current version of the WebStorm-IDE.

Comment: The problem is that `fs` doesn't exist when you deploy to the browser, the browser doesn't have access to the filesystem. You can only `fs` in a Node environment.

Comment: @AndrewLi he's trying to build his application via angular CLI so he's actually in a Node environment

Comment: Try updating the angular CLI to the latest version

Comment: @D.Simon But he's deploying his app to the web right? I'm not terribly familiar with Angular. If he's creating a front-end web-app using Angular he can't use `fs`.

Comment: @AndrewLi Yes but the error doesn't happen in the browser but in the command line while trying to build.

Comment: I clarified where the error occurs: It appears in the browser after compiling and running works like a charm. Still, I'm in the developing stage and not building or deploying for production yet.

Comment: Also, as I said: I'm not doing anything even related to file system operations. In fact, my whole project is a rather simple, pretty straight forward wepapp in which I did nothing but set up some (mostly still empty) components, two services, and some basic routing, triggered by the bootstrap navbar.

Comment: are you using `fs` on the browser?

Comment: No such thing. I just run `ng serve` in a pretty small, easy Angular2 app and browse to localhost:4200, seeing the error in all browsers I tried.

Answer (score 0):

If the same code base working fine earlier and failing later : It seems the issue is with the actual versions of NPM packages installed in both the cases.

**For example :**

- I used an NPM package, say `specialPackage` with version `3.1.0`
- In `package.json` I used it as `~3.1.0`.
- Next day, author of `specialPackage` released a new patch (`3.1.1`) with some breaking change
- I tried my app on a different machine on this day. The same `package.json` installs `3.1.1` instead of `3.1.0`.
- If there is any issue in the third-party NPM package, out app may go down.

**How can we fix this?**

- NPM < 5.0 : One way is to always use exact NPM package versions without `~` or `^` in `package.json`
- NPM >= 5.0 : A new `package-log.json` file will be generated. We need to add this to our repository, so that we expect exact versions of NPM packages that we expected.

**Can you try**

- As you said you are using `NPM >= 5.0`, Do you have a `package-lock.json` available in the repository (where `package-lock.json` was created with the application running fine)
- If not, try to commit the `package-lock.json` from the other computer and then try once again doing `npm i`
- Try using exact NPM package versions in the `package.json` (by removing all `~`s and `^`s.
- Are you using same version of `@angular/cli` global package on both the computers?

Comment: I went back to a commit where the app was still working, branched out, did some changes until the app broke, and then compared the package-lock.json file of both branches: They are identical. :/

Comment: Now I observed something even worse: I do some work, always having a look at my compiled website loading or not. Once I see breaking change happening, I undo my last action, save again, and still see it. /o\